# Select highest value of subquery in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT P.ID,
(
SELECT F.VALUE_ID FROM FORM F
INNER JOIN F.PERSON_ID = P.ID
) AS LATEST_FORM
FROM FORM F1 INNER JOIN PERSON P
ON P.ID = F1.PERSON_ID
WHERE F1.NO_PCP_IND IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY P.ID
```

Each person can have multiple forms and I'm just trying to get the latest form they have submitted. I tried using ROWNUM inside the subquery and I understand why it doesn't work but not sure how to make it generate the right result set with Oracle.

Comment: How do you know which is the latest form? Is there any field that indicates the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query:

```
SELECT P.ID,
       (SELECT F.VALUE_ID
        FROM FORM F INNER JOIN
             F.PERSON_ID = P.ID
       ) AS LATEST_FORM
FROM FORM F1 INNER JOIN
     PERSON P
     ON P.ID = F1.PERSON_ID
WHERE F1.NO_PCP_IND IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY P.ID;
```

In addition to being syntactically incorrect, this would return one row per person *and* user if it worked.  I think your original query should be more like:

```
SELECT P.ID,
       (SELECT F.VALUE_ID
        FROM FORM F
        WHERE F1.NO_PCP_IND IS NOT NULL AND F.PERSON_ID = P.ID AND
              ROWNUM = 1
       ) AS LATEST_FORM
FROM PERSON P
ORDER BY P.ID;
```

This doesn't fix your problem, because you want to keep the last value.  For that, use the `keep` functionality:

```
SELECT P.ID,
       (SELECT MAX(F.VALUE_ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY XXX DESC)
        FROM FORM F
        WHERE F1.NO_PCP_IND IS NOT NULL AND F.PERSON_ID = P.ID
       ) AS LATEST_FORM
FROM PERSON P
ORDER BY P.ID;
```

In this case `XXX` is the name of the column that defines the ordering of the forms for each person.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have never seen the KEEP function before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the `ValueId` which tells about the latest form

So wouldn't this work??

> SELECT max(F.VALUEID), P.ID
>   
>  FROM FORM F, PERSON P
>   
>  where F.PID = P.ID